# Flask-Mongodb: retrieve array of data in a field

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

whenever i do in my mongodb

```
db.knowledge.find({},{'_id':0,'information':0})
```

i'm getting result as

```
{{'keywords': ['link', 'faculty', 'of', 'agriculture', 'admission', 'undergraduate', 'requirements', 'entry', 'full', 'time', 'foa']}
```

i wanted to know how to get it in flask. i'm trying it as

```
dbkeywords = knowledge.find({},{'_id':0,'information':0})
print(dbkeywords[0])
```

i'm getting

```
{'keywords': ['link', 'faculty', 'of', 'agriculture', 'admission', 'undergraduate', 'requirements', 'entry', 'full', 'time', 'foa']}
```

i just want it to be like this:

```
['link', 'faculty', 'of', 'agriculture', 'admission', 'undergraduate', 'requirements', 'entry', 'full', 'time', 'foa']
```

just like an array/list

Comment: You have to unwind the field keywords.

Comment: sorry sir, i'm completely new to flask and mongodb, what does 'unwind the field keywords' means ? help me :/

Comment: In essence: an unwind splits an embedded list into multiple docs. You can take a look at the docs: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html

Comment: Thank you to you, i knew another thing 'unwind' :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the returned data into a dictionary. Then, to access the list itself in `{'keywords': ['link', 'faculty', 'of', 'agriculture', 'admission', 'undergraduate', 'requirements', 'entry', 'full', 'time', 'foa']}`, you just do:

```
temp = {'keywords': ['link', 'faculty', 'of', 'agriculture', 'admission', 'undergraduate', 'requirements', 'entry', 'full', 'time', 'foa']}
the_list = temp['keywords']
print(the_list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, genius :D

Comment: Hello sir , i'm trying to get max value of a field but unable to get any answer 

maxPercentage = findmax.find().sort({'percentagematch':-1.0}).limit(1)
print(maxPercentage)